# Behavior of ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been wondering about specific case around ScheduledExecutorService in java.

Let,

```
ScheduledExecutorService = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);

service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

 @Override
 public void run() {
      //Some task taking longer than schedule period to finish executing.
 }

},initialDelay,period,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

in this case, say period is 4 seconds. When the schedular starts to execute after initialdelay, task will be blocked inside while(true) inifinite loop. 
My question is after each 4 seconds does a task get scheduled disregarding the execution(unfinished) of previous round of task? Because if this is the case this code will crash eventually after running out of memory.

Help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it really matter though? If you have a `while(true)` inside the task, your code is already broken and bad.

Comment: Yea i Know. This is not a real code. It's just the task may take longer than the period, but will eventually return after some time for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the javadoc of `scheduleAtFixedRate()`:

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then
>   subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently
>   execute.

Meaning the task will be started once, but since it never finishes there won't be other invocations. You'll just be wasting one thread in the pool.

The same applies to `scheduleWithFixedDelay()` since the delay is counted from the time when the previous execution finishes (and since it doesn't finish, no next execution can happen).

Comment: Also from the Javadoc _"Successive executions of a periodic task scheduled via `scheduleAtFixedRate` or `scheduleWithFixedDelay` do not overlap. While different executions may be performed by different threads, the effects of prior executions happen-before those of subsequent ones"_

Comment: So does this mean, there won't be queuing of subsequent tasks until the previous one exit? (Thread pool size=1)

Comment: @NowaConcordia if you mean whether tasks pile up, then no. It's only after finishing the task that the next runtime is scheduled, whether immediately or after a delay.